# Seaborn: cumulative sum and hue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, seaborn, visualization

I have the following dataframe in pandas:

```
data = {
    'idx': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
    'hue_val': ["A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C",],
    'value': np.random.rand(30),
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now I want to have a line plot with the cumulative sum over the value by following the "idx" for each "hue_val".
So in the end it would be three curves going strictly up (since they are positive numbers), one for "A", "B" and "C".

I found this code in several sources:

```
sns.lineplot(x="idx", y="value", hue="hue_val", data=df, estimator="cumsum")
```

That is not doing the trick, since both the curve and the x-axis are false:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given OPs dataframe

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
    'idx': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
    'hue_val': ["A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C",],
    'value': np.random.rand(30)
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

There are two things one needs to do:

1. Calculate the cum sum for each `hue_val`
2. Plot it

---

**1. Calculate the cum sum for each `hue_val`**

In order to calculate the cumulative sum, one can use [pandas.DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`pandas.Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html). As per [OP's request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75854837/seaborn-cumulative-sum-and-hue#comment133800614_75854886), use a variable `column` as a way to select the column one wants to consider as follows

```
column = 'value'
df['cum_sum'] = df.groupby('hue_val')[column].cumsum()
```

As one is using Numpy to generate some dataframe values, one can also use it to calculate the cum sum with [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [`numpy.cumsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) as follows

```
df['cum_sum'] = df.groupby('hue_val')[column].apply(lambda x: np.cumsum(x))
```

---

**2. Plot it**

Then one can plot it with [`seaborn.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) as follows

```
sns.lineplot(data=df, x='idx', y='cum_sum', hue='hue_val')
```

[image]

---

**Notes:**

- Having a variable to specify the column, makes it more user friendly if the dataframe has more columns, as the one below, ([one of OP's concern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75854837/seaborn-cumulative-sum-and-hue#comment133800614_75854886)), as one will simply change the variable to, let's say `value3`

  ```
  data = {
      'idx': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
      'hue_val': ["A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C",],
      'value': np.random.rand(30),
      'value1': np.random.rand(30),
      'value2': np.random.rand(30),
      'value3': np.random.rand(30),
  }

  df = pd.DataFrame(data)

  column = 'value3'
  df['cum_sum'] = df.groupby('hue_val')[column].cumsum()

  sns.lineplot(data=df, x='idx', y='cum_sum', hue='hue_val')
  ```

  [image]
- There are strong opinions on using `.apply()`. Would recommend reading this: [When should I (not) want to use pandas apply() in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54432583/7109869)

Answer (score 5):

You can calculate the cumsum separately and plot the result:

```
df['cumsum'] = df.groupby('hue_val').value.transform('cumsum')
sns.lineplot(x="idx", y="cumsum", hue="hue_val", data=df)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way how I can set which "value" I mean if there happen to be a lot more than 3 columns?

Comment: Yes, value here refers to a column name, so you can choose the one you want if there are multiple (in the case the column was actually named 'value').